# Compiling a Java project on Unix using external library mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, unix, ssh

I have a java project that read a database in my local drive and is compiling using Eclipse.
Below is the code that works fine for me.

```
package SQLtest;
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLtest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection connect  =   null;
    Statement statement     =   null;
    ResultSet resultSet     =   null;
    String query        =   "SELECT * FROM abc.publicationlist LIMIT 10"; 

    // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
    // Setup the connection with the DB
    // host = localhost, user = root , password = None, database = abc
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/abc?"+ "user=root&password=");
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while(resultSet.next()){
            String id           = resultSet.getString("id");
            String pubyear      = resultSet.getString("pubyear");
            String title        = resultSet.getString("title");
            String jconfname    = resultSet.getString("jconfname");
            String authors      = resultSet.getString("authors");
            String authorids    = resultSet.getString("authorids");
            System.out.println(id + ":" + pubyear + ":" + title + ":" + jconfname + ":" + authors + ":" + authorids);   
        }
    }
    catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }  
    System.out.print("End of program!!!");
}
```

}

Now I want to move everything to a server using SSH (secure shell). I already move all the database into mysql database server on SSH.
The server name is no longer localhost but change to xxxxxxxx
The username : myname
the password : zzzzzz
I know that I need to change these in the code itself. What I am not familiar with is using a Unix environment to compile a java project that include some external libraries such as mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
[image]

Here is the 2 command that I used

```
[...... src]$ javac -classpath ".:/home/myname/SQLtest/lib" SQLtest/SQLtest.java
[...... src]$ java -cp ".:/home/myname/SQLtest/lib" SQLtest.SQLtest
```

and I get these log error which I don't understand:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at SQLtest.SQLtest.main(SQLtest.java:16)
```

How can I solve this problem ? I am really new to Unix system.

Comment: I think you are doing two things at the same time. Deploy your application outside eclipse and move it to an other plattform. I sugest to first deploy your project standalone, without using eclipse on your dev machine. Then move over to unix.

Comment: You should set your classpath this way: `-classpath ".:/home/myname/SQLtest/lib/*"`

Answer (score 0):

try putting individual jars like `-classpath ".:/home/myname/SQLtest/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar"` and moreover it is a good idea to add the jars into permanent classpath environment vairable and export that.

Comment: this should be a comment